# How do I change the save location of docker containers logs?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I would like to log all stdout messages of my containers to an external drive, as I only have limited space on the 'docker' drive.

With docker-compose v3 I save the logs in 10 MB chunks using the "json-file" driver

```
logging:
  driver: "json-file"
  options:
    max-size: 10m
```

By default the resulting logs are saved at `/var/lib/docker/containers/<container id>/<container id>-json.log`

Is there any way to change this location?

Comment: yes, I am trying to find an answer to this question. To me it seems like it is not possible out of the box and I cannot understand why it is not clearly said.

Answer (score 2):

Straight- forward answer - NO, you can't

Why?

> The file written by the `json-file` logging driver are not intended for
> consumption by external software, and should be regarded the "internal
> storage mechanism" for the `JSON logging driver`. For that reason, the
> location is not configurable.
>
> If you want to have the logs written to a different location, consider
> using (e.g.) the `syslog` driver, `journald`, or one of the drivers that
> allow sending the logs to a central log aggregator

Source: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/29680

Answer (score 1):

You can use another Docker Log Driver for streaming log to External Log Server (Setup in Another Host Machine with external drive).
Docker is supporting many driver:
Description here: https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/configure/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there's an out-of-the-box solution for this.

One thing you can try though is to set lowest limits on your json-file logging driver, but save all the logs in the separate directory like so:

```
docker-compose logs -f 2>&1 | multilog t s1048576 n100 ./my_log_directory
```

You should run this in background to record all the logs

This bit is needed to treat all stderr as stdin so it will be saved by multilog:

```
2>&1
```

More info on multilog here: https://serverfault.com/questions/445118/rotating-logs-generated-by-a-process-that-logs-to-stdin#445461

Although it may work for your needs, you still will loose some information provided by json-file driver